# Preparing to Leave Puppy Home Alone

Tags: dogs, large-dogs

We just got a new bullmastiff puppy. He is currently 10 weeks old. The timing is great because I work from home and will only be returning to in office hours in April.

In April he will be 4 months old, is that old enough to start leaving him alone? My wife will be coming home for lunch so he will have company during lunch but for the rest of the day he will be alone.

Should we rather invest in doggy daycare until he is a bit older? I have been getting mixed messages on this topic.

Thanks,

Filipe